# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? in R 3.2.3

Tags: recursion, infinite

I am trying to run this basic `func` in R, such that `func` can takes values like sum, floor, mean, median, etc. but I always keep getting the error. I am using a windows machine ,R version 3.2.3 .

```
evaluate <- function(func,dat){
    func(dat)
}
```

I tried running like `evaluate(sum,c(4,16))`  but I get

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?